# Python 2 - Logging object containing unicode

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, utf-8

For debug purposes I'm trying to log the content dict that contains unicode strings in it:

```
logging.info(str(data))
```

Where `data` has the following structure:

```
{'whatever®': 1}
```

Obviously when calling `str()` the `UnicodeEncodeError` explodes since it'll try to convert the ® symbol to a bytestring using the ASCII codec under the hood.

As `dict` instances do not have `__unicode__` methods, what would be the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do other than writing my own `toString` function for this kind of data that never convert unicode strings to bytestrings? Is there a utility function I am not aware of in the stdlib or any external lib that I could use?

Comment: Python 2.7 doesn't display dictionaries that way.  What does it really look like?  For example, on my UTF-8 terminal, if I enter `data = {'whatever®':1}` and then view `data`, I get `{'whatever\xc2\xae': 1}` which is a byte string encoded in UTF-8.  This can be logged with no problems.  What do you actually have?

Answer (score 0):

`repr()` function that provides an ambiguous text representation of a Python object is useful for testing, debugging and it seems appropriate for logging: `logging.info(data)` should works as is.

`str(dict_object)` should call `repr(dict_object)` that calls `repr()` on keys and values of the dict recursively that should not raise `UnicodeEncodeError` error (the result contains only printable ascii characters on Python 2).

A possible explanation is that `UnicodeEncodeError` happens during displaying a Unicode content (there is none in the question—there is a bytestring in the example unless you use Python 3 or `from __future__ import unicode_literals`) because the locale is not configured (check `LANG`, `LC_CTYPE`, `LC_ALL` envvars) or the output of the script is redirected to a pipe, file (set `PYTHONIOENCODING` envvar in this case).